# change the dot color of date selection in kal app based on my value

Tags: iphone, calendar

I am new to iphone calendar programming. I using Kal calendar app in my application. Is it possible to change the dot color of date selection in kal app based on my value.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0):

Search "markerImage" in the Kal Project. All images are stored in the Kal.Bundle. You can either modify the images or exchange into your own ones.

Comment: HI Roit - i have made it but in case i would like to hard the value there is any way of doing that.i have tried but what you have said,but it works in their code not in mine

Comment: In your code, you should find something like "Kal Library" in your "Groups & Files". Under the "Kal Library", you can find "Kal.xcodeproj" and "Kal.bundle". If you modified the images, you should find the right images under "Kal.bundle". If you not only modified the images but also the names of image, you have to trace those original images used in Kal library, for example, the KalTileView.m. Of course, you have to change the names into your version.