# changing the images in kal app (kal.bundle)

Tags: iphone, ios, kal

i have found the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434423/change-the-dot-color-of-date-selection-in-kal-app-based-on-my-value) in this link @RoIT suggested that "
Search "markerImage" in the Kal Project. All images are stored in the Kal.Bundle. You can either modify the images or exchange into your own ones." My question is that how can we exchange the images in the Kal.Bundel because when i drag and drop any image in Kal.Bundle , it don't allow dragging and dropping
is it possible to change the images only not the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open "Kal.bundle" in Finder (Show Package Contents). Then it is just like any other folder, and you can move the images in there around.

If that somehow does not work, check that the folders are not read-only (Show Info in Finder).